# Scripts in JMeter run successfully but doesn't do the required functionality on my application

Tags: performance, load-testing, jmeter

I just started using JMeter. I recorded a test script successfully. Now that I replay my test scripts it doesn't do the required functionality that it was meant to do. More over the process i recorded took me about 5mins to record but the scripts run successfully in 30seconds.

Can anyone please help me? JMeter doesn't show anything in the errors log. All scripts are marked successful and the errors in the summary report are 0%.

Comment: What you have set for No. of thread , ramp up period and loop count? Also in which pages you are putting load? please share your test plan.

Comment: No of thread, ramp up period and loop count is 1.

Comment: I just recorded a test case using the recording controller and i am replaying it.

Comment: Why you are recording? any specific requirement?

Comment: I need to make some orders in my application. I need to put load later on if it can handle 100-200 orders at a time. Ordering process consists of 5 steps. (selecting customizations and all)

Comment: Can this be done any other way? I think i could only record the process and replay it. Putting load on the replay. Eg. Start 50 orders at a time and all.

Comment: Do you using : HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder  ?

Comment: See my updated answer as per your requirement how can you perform in jmeter.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I have a same problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) enabled
2. Make sure that you properly handle any dynamic mandatory parameters like "VIEWSTATE", "SESSIONID", etc. Record the same sequence several times and look for any request parameters which are different. If they are, you'll need to correlate them by extracting dynamic bits from previous response via

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

   and add those as parameters into next request.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for reference, it assumes some .NET specific dynamic parameters, however the approach should be the same for any backend technology.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to achieve your testing goal :

1 - Create thread group with following option :

```
No. of threads : 100
Ramp up period : 300 Seconds [5 Minutes]
loop count : 0 [ZERO]
```

2 - Add listeners [To see result of load] ,  1 - View result tree , 2 - Summary report.

3 - Record your test using :  HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - Perform all scenario in you site you want.

4 - Stop recording when you complete site surf.

5 - Run this test plan and see result that how your site behave when 100 users come to site and surf till 5 minutes continue.

Let me know if you get any confusion in above.

Comment: I ran my test plan with these settings you mentioned. It ran for 5mins but didn't show any result in the listerners (View result tree and Summary report). However the log showed that it ran successfully. No orders were made in my application though.

Comment: For now i just want my recorded test case to replay and make an order like i do manually. Ill put in the load later.

Comment: It must show result. Do you getting list of urls below thread group  which you surfed during recording?

Comment: Yes i am. About 300-400 URLs.

Comment: Then result must be there. hope you are running jmeter test after stop recording.

Comment: Yes i am. I stopped recording and then ran the tests. The test takes only 25seconds to run it all. Can this be the reason that it didnt reach the end in this time? Would increasing the duration time make it happen?

Comment: No..It does not matter. even if test run for 10 seconds then also result must be there in listeners.

Comment: Results is there in the listener but not on my orders page in the application. I should see in my application that the order is made or not. Results come up in the listeners. No issues there.

Comment: Then you need to put individual listener for each URL. Please put listener for each URL.

Comment: There are about 300-400 urls.

Comment: Yes but not all are important. you can put listener for only main pages.